# Hibernate configuration property not supported by Quarkus application.properties

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I am using Quarkus 2.9.2.Final and would like to set a Hibernate config parameter, which is not one of the "chosen ones" which can go into Quarkus' `application.properties` as per the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config).

Specifically I would like to set this Hibernate configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy"
          value="org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.inline.InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy"
/>
```

to prevent Hibernate from generating temporary tables (as described [here](https://in.relation.to/2017/02/01/non-temporary-table-bulk-id-strategies/)).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe an option is to abandon application.properties and reintroduce persistence.xml? I will try.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties` ([ref](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#quarkus-hibernate-orm_quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties-full-property-key)) config?